# What are some good references for understanding the conjugate gradient method?

Tags: reference-request

Are there any good references that provide an intuitive, motivated, or visual explanation of the conjugate gradient method?

Comment: I have used Conjugate Gradient Method for one of my problems in the past and I used the algorithm given on page 52 of "An Introduction to the Conjugate Gradient Method Without the Agonizing Pain (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf). Worked quite nicely for my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A great reference for the conjugate gradient method is

[*An Introduction to the Conjugate Gradient Method Without the Agonizing Pain* by Jonathan Richard Shewchuk (1994)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.110.418)

The author writes in the first paragraph:

> When I decided to learn the Conjugate Gradient Method (henceforth, CG), I read four different descriptions, which I shall politely not identify. I understood none of them. Most of them simply wrote down the method, then proved its properties without any intuitive explanation or hint of how anybody might have invented CG in the first place. This article was born of my frustration, with the wish that future students of CG will learn a rich and elegant algorithm, rather than a confusing mass of equations.

Not only does the author provide a clear explanation of the conjugate gradient method using diagrams, but they also provide great intuitive explanations for its convergence properties.